# Dropdown value disappears after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a textbox whose values goes into the dropdown on button click. The problem is that when I fill all the data and submit the form. And when I come second time to see that value it disappears from the dropdown. What should I do to make the value gets in the dropdown fix. Please see the code for your reference:

```
 <tr>
        <td class="td">Location/City</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqLocation" ControlToValidate="ddlLocation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter location" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherCity" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="txtfld-popup"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddDropDown" runat="server" Width="63" Text="Add" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAddDropDown_Click1" />

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Also, see the code behind for your reference:-

```
 protected void ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlLocation.SelectedItem.Text == "Other")
    {
        txtOtherCity.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        txtOtherCity.Visible = false;
    }
}
protected void btnAddDropDown_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string city = txtOtherCity.Text.Trim();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
    {
        ddlLocation.Items.Add(new ListItem(city, city));
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you populating the the drop down?

Comment: There is two dropdown, whose values are coming from a table. Its state and city table. when user selects a state their respective cities are been visible. If some cities are not been mentioned than user can add that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this solution, Please see the code for your reference:-

```
protected void BindContrydropdown()
{
    //conenction path for database
    //string connection = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Id,CityName From Career.Location", con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        ddllocation1.DataSource = ds;
        ddllocation1.DataTextField = "CityName";
        ddllocation1.DataValueField = "Id";
        ddllocation1.DataBind();
        ddllocation1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        ddllocation1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("--OTHER--", "0"));
        con.Close();
    }
}
protected void ddllocation1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string country = "India";

    var cities = _helper.GetLocations(country, ddllocation1.SelectedValue);
    cities.Insert(0, "--Select--");
    cities.Insert(1, "Other");
    ddlLocation.DataSource = cities;
    ddlLocation.DataBind();

}
protected void btnAddDropDown_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();
        //BindContrydropdown();
        //if (txtOtherCity.Text != "")
        //{

        //    txtOtherCity.Text = "";
        //}
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Add_CityforLocation";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CountryName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "India";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtOtherCity.Text.Trim();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddlLocation.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        try
        {
            // con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            BindContrydropdown();
            // lblMessage.Text = "City inserted successfully!";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);//You Can Haave Messagebox here
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also see the html of the dropdowns:-

```
<tr>
        <td class="td">Location/State</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddllocation1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddllocation1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ControlToValidate="ddllocation1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter location" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="td">Location/City</td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="txtfld-popup" ID="ddlLocation" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocation_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator CssClass="error_msg" ID="reqLocation" ControlToValidate="ddlLocation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter location" InitialValue="--Select--" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherCity" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="txtfld-popup"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddDropDown" runat="server" Width="63" Text="Add" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnAddDropDown_Click1" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

And this solved my,
Also see the Stored procedure for the same:-

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Add_CityforLocation]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@ID int,
@CountryName nvarchar(100),
@StateName nvarchar(100),
@CityName varchar(100)
```

AS
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO Career.Location(CountryName, StateName, CityName) values (@CountryName,@StateName,@CityName)
END
GO

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the values from the textbox into the table dbo.Cities in database. Next time when you will come back to the same page then dropdown will fetch data from db.

Comment: Can you help me with some code, how to store that value in the table when user adds the data in the dropdown ?

Comment: You can either use sql queries within the c# code or you can use DAL and BLL. First one is for learning purpose and doesn't comes under 3 -layer architecture. So you better search for that and use the code what #Rain has provided you.

Comment: Need more help on this, as How to add the code to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Then on `btnAddDropDown_Click1()` you should insert the value of the city from the 'txtOtherCity' `TextBox` to the respective table, and then bind the `DropDown` of the city again. Something Like

```
 protected void btnAddDropDown_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          string strconnection =            System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["YourConnectionString"].ToString();
            string city = txtOtherCity.Text.Trim();
            DataSet ds=new DataSet();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(city))
            {
                // Your code to insert the value of the city from the 'txtOtherCity'           `TextBox` to the respective table
                 //Edit: this is a very rudimentary code
                 string query = "INSERT INTO Career.Location (State) " + 
                       "VALUES (@city) ";

        // create connection and command
          using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strconnection))
          using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
           {
            // define parameters and their values
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = city;

            // open connection, execute INSERT, close connection
            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

            }
            query = "select State from Career.Location";
            using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(strconnection))
            using(SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand(query, cnn))
           {  
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);            
            cnn.Open();
            adp .Fill(ds);
            cnn.Close();

            }
             ddlLocation.DataSource=ds;
             ddlLocation.DataTextField = "State";
             ddlLocation.DataValueField = "State";
             ddlLocation.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: its is giving me System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at line string strconnection = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Do you have functionality of inserting the data in the DB (not only adding the new item in the drop down list). You have to insert the city in the appropriate table to be able to see it later on.

The implementation depends on your architecture, the implementation of the DAL etc. 
For example - if you are using ADO.NET, you can insert the values in the table with a stored procedure:

`CREATE PROCEDURE Add_City
    @CityName varchar(50),
    @StateID int
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Cities (CityName, StateID) values (@CityName, @StateID)
END
GO`

And then call it from the app. Something like that:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("the connection string"))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.CommandText = "Add_City";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CityName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtCity.Text.Trim();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@StateID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CountryId;

            cmd.Connection = con;

            try
            {

                con.Open();

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // lblMessage.Text = "City inserted successfully!";

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex; // Or log or handle somehow the exception

            }

        }
```

Comment: I dont have any functionality to insert the city in the table, thats what I want.

Comment: This code is to be written on btnAdd click. Right ?

Comment: Yes, into the If check. That will add the new item. (It's not tested, so you might need to tune it a little)

Comment: Okay, will implement and let u know.

Comment: @Svileen: It is giving me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Comment: @Saba: For the second parameter I have been written @ Country, but according to the stored procedure it should be @ StateID (I corrected it in the sample). And that should add the record in the DB. State ID or name must be got from anywhere. Your ID column should be primary key and must be auto incremented. If not - change the code according to your DB schema (fix the names of the table and the columns, pass the additional required fields, etc.)

Comment: Hi, I added the code but it is going in catch. And is giving me error like this "Procedure or function 'Add_CityforLocation' expects parameter '@ID', which was not supplied." Please see my code in JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8vegzqu/3/ –

Comment: You should pass the @ ID, @ CountryName and @ StateName to the stored procedure: cmd.Parameters.Add(...).Value = ...

Comment: Hi, Please see my jsfiddle for the full code http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7o1y9x/, whenever I add the BindContrydropdown() to pageload it gives me 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'StateName'. Also, the value  is not inserted in the CityDropdown